# Izimodal not showing non-latin letters

Tags: javascript, html, izimodal

Seems like izimodal not showing non-latin letter's. Html template has utf-8 set

Here is html example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
        <title>Message from {shop_name}</title>
```

I tried to play with html template but nothing seems to help
Anyone had this problem before and maybe can guide me how i can fix this issue?

Comment: add `  <meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: Tried didn't help